# About Renaming a Batch File Using a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

Good Day guys !

I'm New in This " Batch File " things And Recently , i'm working on a Expirment on how to rename   a Batch File ( Cause i still have many Complications and confusions on that Part ) using a Batch File ..

At my C Drive is were i put the Batch File which i'm trying to rename ..
heres the Full path :

```
C:/CARLOS/MyFiles
```

in the folder "MyFiles" is were i put The File that i will rename.
the Folder's name is goat and i wanted to rename it with monkey ..
i already Tried This :

```
@echo off
cd C:/CARLOS/MyFiles
ren "goat" "monkey"
```

when i clicked that , It will just say that " Can't find the specific File "

i Hope You Can Help Me !! =D

Answer (score 3):

You are probably missing the file extensions because you have to specify *full* filenames within batch-files. A batch-file usually has an extension `.bat` or `.cmd`.

```
ren goat.bat monkey.bat
```